# Sorting and Displaying an Object Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, object

I'm somewhat new to programming, and I'm trying to display a printed array of objects. I keep getting this compile error:

SchoolTextBookSort.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
                                System.out.println(textBooks[x].bubbleSortAuthor() + " ");
                                                               ^
  symbol:   method bubbleSortAuthor()
  location: class SchoolTextBook
1 error

Here is the code making the error. Can someone please help me?

```
    if (response.equals("AUTHOR"))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < textBooks.length; ++x)
        {
            System.out.println(textBooks[x].bubbleSortAuthor() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid Response.");
}

public static void bubbleSortAuthor(SchoolTextBook[] array)
{
    int a, b;
    SchoolTextBook temp;
    int highSubscript = array.length - 1;

    for (a = 0; a < highSubscript; ++a)
        for(b = 0; b < highSubscript; ++b)
            if (array[b].getAuthorName().compareTo(array[b + 1].getAuthorName()) < 0)
            {
                temp = array[b];
                array[b] = array[b + 1];
                array[b + 1] = temp;
            }               
}
```

Comment: Is the variable `textBooks` an `array` or an `array of an array` (2D array)?

Comment: If an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks. (You also get points for accepting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call bubbleSortAuthor by passing it the array rather than calling it on the array.

Like this:

```
bubbleSortAuthor(textBooks);
```

It is static but takes an array as an argument and is a method belonging to the class you are in so you don’t need

```
YourClassName.bubbleSortAuthor(textBooks);
```

From within the same class

Also, it returns void and you can’t print void.  You should loop through the array again to print it once it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few small errors, explained below.

1. You are not passing the `textbooks` array to the method `bubbleSortAuthor(SchoolTextBook[])`. It seems you are trying to call the method on the SchoolTextBook objects which are in the array.
2. You cannot call static methods from a class object. You have to either call it  like

   ```
   bubbleSortAuthor(array);                       // if calling it from inside the class
   ```

   or use the class name

   ```
   SchoolTextBook.bubbleSortAuthor(array);       // from anywhere - if declared public
   ```
3. Your bubble sort algorithm is not correct. The inner for loop should be written as:

   ```
   for(b = 0; b < highSubscript -a; ++b) {       // you were missing the -a
   ```

---

Method **.compareTo(String)**

> public int compareTo(String anotherString)
>
> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

By using `>` below, we are sorting in ascending order. This also means that capital letters come before lower case letters (ASCII). In case you didn't want that behavior you can apply `.toLowerCase()` to the elements before comparison.

More on the .compareTo() method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

---

Here is the **corrected code**:

```
if (response.equals("AUTHOR")) {
    for (int x = 0; x < textBooks.length; ++x) {
        // if textBooks is 2D array of SchoolTextBook objects then call it like this
        bubbleSortAuthor(textBooks[x]);
    }

    // if textBooks is 1D array of SchoolTextBook objects then you don't need the
    // above for loop. You could just write: 
    // bubbleSortAuthor(textBooks);

    // print results
    for(SchoolTextBook textBook : textBooks) {
        System.out.println(textBook.getAuthorName());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Response.");
}

public static void bubbleSortAuthor(SchoolTextBook[] array) {
    int a, b, arrayLength = array.length;
    SchoolTextBook temp;

    for (a = 0; a < arrayLength - 1; ++a) {
        for(b = 0; b < arrayLength - 1 - a; ++b) {
            if (array[b].getAuthorName().compareTo(array[b + 1].getAuthorName()) > 0) {
                temp = array[b];
                array[b] = array[b + 1];
                array[b + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```